# How to deploy uniswap contract with open zeppelin?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, ganache, openzeppelin, uniswap

I was following the quick start [here](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/quick-start/) which suggests to "Deploy the `UniswapV2Factory`" under the writing tests header. I'm using OpenZeppelin and have Ganache running but I wasn't able to deploy the contract. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running `npx oz deploy node_modules/@uniswap/v2-core/build/Combined-Json.json` and I get the error:

```
[2020-08-25T22:25:29.809Z@errors.js#call] <started> Error: Invalid contract 'node_modules/@uniswap/v2-core/build/Combined-Json.json'
    at throwIfInvalid (/Prototypes/ethereum-prototype/node_modules/@openzeppelin/cli/lib/register-command.js:166:15)
    at /Prototypes/ethereum-prototype/node_modules/@openzeppelin/cli/lib/register-command.js:122:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Prototypes/ethereum-prototype/node_modules/@openzeppelin/cli/lib/register-command.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```